# Does convergence in probability imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \varepsilon_n) = 0$ for any $\varepsilon_n$?

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $X_n \overset{P}{\to} X$ i.e. for all $\varepsilon > 0$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \varepsilon) = 0 .
$$

Let $(\varepsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any sequence of $\varepsilon$'s bounded by $1$. Does
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \varepsilon_n) = 0 ?
$$

I'm thinking this is false but have a hard time coming up with a counter example, any ideas?

Comment: Just a remark: if you are looking for counter examples concerning random variables then it is a good custom to start your search at *degenerated random variables*. The answer of Kavi testifies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon =\frac 1 n$, $X_n=\frac  2 n$ and $X=0$.

Then $X_n \to X$ in probability but $P(|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon_n)=1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.